# I am trying to pass a variable from a procedure as input into another procedure netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to pass the formBuyerAggressiveness into a bidTargetPrice procedure. It is giving a "Expected reporter" error message. Here is my code thus far.

```
to bidTargetPrice [tradeID]

   let buyerAggressiveness [formBuyerAggresiveness] of tradeID

  ; if ( buyerAggresiveness <= 1 ) [
   ifelse (- 1 < buyerAggresiveness) and (buyerAggresiveness <= 0)
        [report equilibriumPrice * (1 - ( ( ( e ^ (- buyerAggresiveness * theta ) ) - 1) / (e ^ theta - 1) ) )
          ]

        [report equilibriumPrice + ( (value - equilibriumPrice) * ( ( (e ^ (buyerAggresiveness * theta) ) - 1 ) / ( (e ^ theta) - 1) ) )
          ]
 ;  ]
```

The following is the procedure which I call in the above procedure. I intend to pass the buyers aggressiveness parameter into a procudere that helps form the price.

```
to formBuyerAggresiveness 
     ;define some local parameters


      ifelse (transactionPrice > 0.0 ) 
        [ ifelse (bidTargetPrice >= transactionPrice) 
             [ let desiredAggressiveness ( ( (1 - C2 ) * rshout) - C1 ) ;rshout is the degree of aggressiveness that would form a price equal to the  last bid
               report buyerAggressiveness (degreeOfAggressiveness  + B1 * (desiredAggressiveness - degreeOfAggressiveness) )             ;degreeOfAggressiveness is a random of individual trader aggressiveness from -1 to 1 range. *defined during init user/buyer
             ]

             [ let desiredAggressiveness ( ( (1 + C2 ) * rshout) + C1 ) ;buyer must be more aggresive
             report degreeOfAggressiveness  + B1 * (desiredAggressiveness - degreeOfAggressiveness)
              ] 
        ]

         [ if (bid?) and (bidTargetPrice <= bestBid) 
            [let desiredAggressiveness ( ( (1 + C2 ) * rshout) + C1 )
             report degreeOfAggressiveness  + B1 * (desiredAggressiveness - degreeOfAggressiveness)
              ]
         ]
end
```

Comment: Why did you use report formBuyerAggresiveness ? For me it's not a reporter context and you can use set . But I don't know where do you call `formBuyerAggresiveness`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line `let buyerAggressiveness [formBuyerAggresiveness] of tradeID`.  There error message is telling you that `[formBuyerAggresiveness]` is not a reporter.  The phrase `[attrA] of myagent` only works when `myagent` (i) is an agent and (ii) has this attribute.

To fix this, you have at least two choices.

1. give your agent an `aggressiveness` attribute and write a procedure to `set` it, so you can then access it with `[aggressiveness] of myagent`, or
2. write a *reporter* that takes an agent as an argument and returns an aggressiveness value for that agent

Comment: Thanks for a heads up. I decided to make formBuyerAggressiveness a reporter it seems to have solved the issue. I also considered what was stated by Delaye. I have a question on a related issue. Is it possible to use a report procedure output as part of an if statement in another report procedure?

Comment: If you have a new question, please open a new question, rather than just adding comments onto an existing one.